# Tree that efficiently avoids duplicate values in ancestors

Tags: data-structures, tree, set

The question is pretty simple:

1. I have a (potentially very unbalanced) tree.
2. At every iteration, new children are appended to some node.
3. However, children with values duplicated in their ancestors must be filtered out.

Is there a (hopefully simple) way to maintain this data structure efficiently?

The obvious ways require *O(depth(node))* time per append, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score -2):

Use AVL Trees or Binary Search Trees(BST). You have to apply a small logic to avoid duplicates in the AVL/BST. That logic: Use only >,< operator in tree building. never use >=, =< operators. //Pseudo code:

```
if(present_node_value<new_node_value)
insert_in_left_side
else if(present_node_value>new_node_value)
insert_in_right_side
else    // Means duplicate entry
print " Duplicate Entry"
return
```